# iOS 13 UITextField inputView with UIPickerView causing app to not be interact-able

Tags: swift, uipickerview, ios13

I have the following code that worked before for making a `UITableView` cell tap to show a `UIPickerView` on screen:

```
fileprivate var hiddenField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: .zero)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //...
    hiddenField.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(hiddenField)
}

func selectYear() {
    let yearPicker = UIPickerView()
    yearPicker.dataSource = self
    yearPicker.delegate = self

    hiddenField.inputView = yearPicker
    hiddenField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

However on iOS 13.1 simulator this code now makes it so that I can't tap anywhere in the app (can't scroll the picker view, or tap anywhere else), but the simulator is responsive since I can swipe up on the home indicator to close the app.

Did anything change regarding how this code might run on iOS 13 vs previously?

Comment: also seeing this issue.  did you ever find a solution?

Comment: restarting Xcode and the simulator fixed it for me, seemed to be a glitch that once it happened, it wouldn't stop until I restarted